# Call Customer Group ID for invoice PDF

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, create-invoice

I am trying to create a note on a PDF invoice which is only shown for a specific customer group. I use Magento 1.9.2.4 with the Firegento PDF Extension.

**My code so far is:**

```
public function addTaxNotes(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
     $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); 
        if($groupId = 6) {
             $page = $observer->getPage();
        $page->drawText('Tax-exempt intra-Community supply according 4 Nr.1b UstG i.V. § 6aUStG ', 0, 120, 'UTF-8');
        return $this;
        }
        }
```

My problem is, that the "if" function doesn`t work. The note is shown to all customer no matter which customer group they belong to. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison is using a "=" instead of a "==" operator:

```
if($groupId = 6) {
```

Change to

```
if($groupId == 6) {
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but this won`t solve the problem unfortunaly. If I change it to "==" the text is not shown at all. It seems that somehow the GroupId is not called correctly. Using for example the Country Code instead of the Customer Group it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `if ($groupId = 6) {` you are assign the value to groupid. not check. Please change and check `if ($groupId == 6) {`

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code.

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$groupId = $customer->getGroupId();
if($groupId == 6) {
```

Hope it will work.